# Passing parameter from jquery post method to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send "name" as a parameter to controller, but controller is not receiving the parameter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    var name = $("#search").val();
    //name = "ali";
    alert(name);
    $.post("/Status/searchByName", { typeId: name }, function (data) {
      document.write(data);
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        //document.write(data,value);
        // Here you can iterate data one by one and process it.
      });
    }, "text");           
  });
});
```

here is action method

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult searchByName(string name)
{           
  dbCRMEntities dbx = new dbCRMEntities();         
  var names = dbx.CONTACTS.Where(chk => name == chk.NAME);
  return this.Json(names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
}
```

this action method is receiving only null

Comment: try public JsonResult searchByName(string typeId)

Answer (score 7):

Your passing `{ typeId: name }` but you method expects a parameter named `name`

Change the parameter to

```
public JsonResult searchByName(string typeId)
```

or alternatively adjust the script to

```
$.post("/Status/searchByName", { name: name }, function (data) {
```